# How can I read a .csv file in R using Rserve to communicate with PHP on a LAMP system?

Tags: php, r, csv, rserve

I would like to read the .csv file into R. I have been able to send the absolute path of the file to R and it will return it via the `$test` variable in the PHP code below. The `$r->evalString("data<-read.csv(filetim,header=TRUE)");` returns an error that I have listed below. Any ideas as to what is causing the error?

```
<?php 
require_once 'rconfig.php';
require 'rConnection.php';
try {
    # Connect to R via Rserve
    echo '<p>Connecting to Rserve '.RSERVE_HOST;
    $r = new Rserve_Connection(RSERVE_HOST);
    echo ' Connection OK</p>';
    # Associate filename with the file's absolute path
    $r->evalString("filetim=('folder/folder/folder/file.csv')");
    $r->evalString("filebob=('folder/folder/folder/file2.csv')");
    # Check if the filename is being stored
    $test = $r->evalString("filebob");
    echo $test;
    # Read the .csv file into variable "data"
    $r->evalString("data<-read.csv(filetim,header=TRUE)");
    $r->close();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
?>
```

Error:

`'Rserve_Exception' with message 'unable to evaluate' in /folder/folder/folder/folder/folder/rConnection.php:239 Stack trace: #0 /folder/folder/folder/folder/folder/rcodetest.php(17): Rserve_Connection->evalString('data<-read.csv(f...') #1 {main}`

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes you're on a Linux system. For Windows (if you got Rserve to work...) the story is the same.

The path you gave to `read.csv` is not an absolute, but a relative path. R starts from the working directory (by default often the user home directory on Linux systems, indicated in R by `~`)

In your case,the absolute path would be

```
$r->evalString("filetim=('/folder/folder/folder/file.csv')");
```

To find out what R considers the working directory, you can use `getwd()`. Using `try()`, you can catch error messages inside R to get a better idea of what went wrong, as explained on the page of Rserve here : http://rforge.net/Rserve/faq.html#errors

You can also use a `tryCatch()` in R to get the R error message or the warning message. In the specific case of `read.csv()` the warning message might be more useful than the error (which simply says "cannot open the connection")

eg:

```
$err = $r->evalString("tryCatch(read.csv(filetim,header=TRUE), error = function(e) e)");
echo $err;
```

to catch the error, or

```
$err = $r->evalString("tryCatch(read.csv(filetim,header=TRUE), warning = function(w) w)");
echo $err;
```

to catch the warning. This should give you an idea about where R is looking for your file. Note that you might have to wrap the whole call to tryCatch in `as.character()`. I'm not sure if Rserve in combination with php can handle simpleWarning objects.